# Android Studio - libmp3lame NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, mp3

I am currently trying to implement libmp3lame into my Android Application in order to decode MP3 data into PCM.

To use libmp3lame, I need to use JNI/NDK implementation, and to decode MP3 into PCM I need to use the hip_decode() function from libmp3lame.

This function is instantiated like this the "lame.h" file:

```
int CDECL hip_decode( hip_t           gfp
                , unsigned char * mp3buf
                , size_t          len
                , short           pcm_l[]
                , short           pcm_r[]
                );
```

My application works like this:
I receive one mono MP3 sample from a WebSocket. I need to decode this sample from MP3 to PCM and then write it into my AudioTrack to play it. It is live stream so I need the lowest latency possible. I was using JLayer and I could understand perfectly what was the speaker saying but I had a "hash" problem / robotic voice. It seemed like I had some 0 value at the beginning of each sample and it caused some weird effect. Now I need to do the same with libmp3lame. So what I want to do is the following. Everytime my WebSocket even reception is called, I need to take the byte array received (containing the audio data) and decode it into PCM. I need to have byte[] or short[] in PCM and then play it in audio track. Problem is I'm not sure how to use the hip_decode to do so. I'm really not familiar with C programming so there might be a very simple way to do it but I just can't do it. Right now in my wrapper.c I have this :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_jneb_myapplication_MainActivity_decoderInit(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj,
    ) {
    hip = hip_decode_init();

}
```

I'm not sure what are the pcm_l and pcm_r needed to use the hip_decode function. Here is some more information regarding the function :

```
/*********************************************************************
* input 1 mp3 frame, output (maybe) pcm data.
*
*  nout = hip_decode(hip, mp3buf,len,pcm_l,pcm_r);
*
* input:
*    len          :  number of bytes of mp3 data in mp3buf
*    mp3buf[len]  :  mp3 data to be decoded
*
* output:
*    nout:  -1    : decoding error
*           0    : need more data before we can complete the decode
*           >0    : returned 'nout' samples worth of data in pcm_l,pcm_r
*    pcm_l[nout]  : left channel data
*    pcm_r[nout]  : right channel data
*
*********************************************************************/
```

EDIT: 
Thanks to bukkojot answer I've been able to understand what were pcm_l & pcm_r used for.

Here is an update of my code :

```
JNIEXPORT jshortArray JNICALL Java_com_example_jneb_myapplication_AudioTrackClass_decoderInit(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj,
                                                                                     jbyteArray data, jint size) {
jsize mp3Len =  (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data);
// Print the data.length = 96
LOGI("JNI integer: %d", mp3Len);
// mp3 contains all 96 values
jbyte *mp3 = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data, 0);

// Trying to decode mp3 into PCM
int x = hip_decode(hip, (unsigned char*) mp3, (size_t) mp3Len, pcm_l, pcm_r);

jshortArray pcmBuffer;
pcmBuffer = (*env)->NewShortArray(env, mp3Len);
(*env)->SetShortArrayRegion(env, pcmBuffer, 0, mp3Len, pcm_l);
// Releasing byte array
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data, mp3, 0);

// Returning
return pcmBuffer;
```

}

Right now pcmBuffer only return 0 value, and the hip_decode only returns 0 value too. The doc says that if hip_decode return 0 then the hip_decode function "need more data before we can complete the decode". I'm already giving the function all the data I have. What am I doing wrong with the hip_decode function ?

Answer (score 2):

> 'm not sure what are the pcm_l and pcm_r needed to use the hip_decode
>   function.

This is the pointers to buffers, where decoded PCM will be written.

Alloc somewhere enough memory for uncompressed sound like:

```
signed short *pcm_l=malloc(1000000); // make sure it's enough
signed short *pcm_r=malloc(1000000);
```

And then just pass them to decoding function. Function will return number of useful samples. Pass this data to Java part and write to AudioTrack.

Comment: Ok I'll try this out. Do my buffer need to be that big though ? This function will be called for each small chunk of mp3 data, won't this cause a memory problem ?

Comment: If you alloc memory only in init, you will use only 2mb of memory. This is very small in our days. If you want more precise, calculate maximum size of audio what can be uncompressed, for example, 5 seconds * 48000 samplerate * 2 bytes per sample = 480000 bytes per channel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, allowed me to understand what I'm supposed to do. I edited the question since I'm still facing some problem.

Comment: At first, if you want return pointer, you must `return pcm_l;`, not `return *pcm_l;`. Secondly, you must define allocation in some other place, or you will very soon reach "out of memory", do it only in init function. And last, read about copy data to Java world.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. What do you mean about "copy data to Java world?" I'd like to read about it but I don't really know what you are referring to.

Comment: Google for GetShortArrayElements, memcpy and ReleaseShortArrayElements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into that !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159584/discussion-between-jineb92-and-bukkojot).

Comment: I spent enough time, so I don't want to chat

Comment: Ok no problem. Thanks for all your help :).